# How to save a multidimentional array to database in Joomla 3.0 or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, joomla3.0

I have a multidimensional array which can be varying in length from 1 to 40+ arrays within an array that I need to add to a database table in Joomla 3.  Here is a sample one with 4 arrays:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => cbb807
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] => 8
                    [4] => Polycorp3-1
                    [5] => Polycorp3
                    [6] => 18
                    [7] => 339.00000
                    [8] => 339.00000
                    [9] => 339.00000
                    [10] => 82
                    [11] => 2250
                    [12] => Phone
                    [13] => Polycorpm
                    [14] => Jones

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => cbb807
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] => 8
                    [4] => Polycorp3-1
                    [5] => Polycorp3
                    [6] => 18
                    [7] => 339.00000
                    [8] => 339.00000
                    [9] => 339.00000
                    [10] => 82
                    [11] => 2250
                    [12] => Phone
                    [13] => Polycorpm
                    [14] => Jones

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => cbb807
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] => 8
                    [4] => Polycorp3-1
                    [5] => Polycorp3
                    [6] => 18
                    [7] => 339.00000
                    [8] => 339.00000
                    [9] => 339.00000
                    [10] => 82
                    [11] => 2250
                    [12] => Phone
                    [13] => Polycorpm
                    [14] => Jones
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => cbb807
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] => 8
                    [4] => Polycorp3-1
                    [5] => Polycorp3
                    [6] => 18
                    [7] => 339.00000
                    [8] => 339.00000
                    [9] => 339.00000
                    [10] => 82
                    [11] => 2250
                    [12] => Phone
                    [13] => Polycorpm
                    [14] => Jones
                )

        )
```

The code I have doing this is:

```
    $dbo = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $dbo->getQuery(true);


$columns = array( 'ordering', 'state', 'checked_out', 'created_by', 'devicetype', 'manufacturer', 'model', 'serialnumber', 'market', 'cost', 'date_purchased', 'partner', 'current_customer', 'current_location', 'original_customer', 'date_recieved', 'date_recently_deployed', 'notes', 'ordernumber', 'status', 'ist', 'arp', 'walken', 'cheese', 'pt_id', 'budgeted_cost', 'firmware', 'other_ist', 'sell_price', 'current_term');

$values = array();


foreach ($data as $key => $array) {
$values = array(1,1,0,82,$db->quote($data['12']),$db->quote($data['13']),$db->quote($data['5']),$db->quote($Serial_Number),$db->quote($Market),$db->quote($data['7']),$db->quote($Date_Purchased),$db->quote($data['14']),$db->quote($data['11']),$db->quote($Current_Location),$db->quote($Previous_Customer),$db->quote($Date_Recieved),$db->quote($Date_Time_was_deployed_currently),$db->quote($Notes),$db->quote($Order_Number),$db->quote($Status),$db->quote($aa),$db->quote($bb),$db->quote($cc),$db->quote($dd),$db->quote($deviceId),$db->quote($Budgeted_Costs),$db->quote($Firmware),$db->quote($ee),$db->quote($Sell_Price),$db->quote($Current_Term_in_Months));

}



$query->insert($dbo->quoteName('#__inventory_einventoryitems'));
$query->columns($columns);

$query->values($values);

$dbo->setQuery($query);
$dbo->execute();
```

The problem I am running into is that it runs, but it seems to be returning ARRAY() and nothing is saved to the database.   It seems like it should work.   I know I have a mistake,  I just can not see where.

I would prefer to use joomla classes, but if someone has a better solution in php/mysql.  I am open to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to store it in MySQL by using pure php then simplest way to use some extension like a 'JUMI' which lets you to use php in joomla, without using the joomla classes.
here is the link to joomi extension:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/jumi

Comment: I've used things like that before.  In this case I have this buried in a controller.  So it is not accessing any articles or modules. I think the error I have is in how i am performing the foreach loop.  It seems like it should be correct, but I dont think i am doing it right.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your code right, but I think in value row into foreach you have to use $array, not $data. ... No, no you've swaped variables in foreach - it has to be foreach($array as $key=>$data)

Comment: That might have been part of it.  But now I get an error:
Error: 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 SQL=INSERT INTO `jyxdf_inventory_einventoryitems` (ordering, state, checked_out, created_by, devicetype, manufacturer, model, serialnumber, market, cost, date_purchased, partner, current_customer, current_location, original_customer, date_recieved, date_recently_deployed, notes, ...   ) VALUES (1),(1),(0),(82),(''),(''),(''),(''),(''),(''),(''),(''),(''),(''),(''),...  
I counted and the lengths are fine.  30 and 30   I don't know why I'm seeing this error

Comment: Yes, taht was first part of problem - if you got this message, it means now you are going into foreach cycle now. The second problem is that you have 30 columns, but 29 values - count them again - I've done it too.

Comment: Thanks for looking!  I have done that as well.  
But there are 30 each.  I counted several times and placed into a text editor and counted mechanically too.  also, what is interesting is that I am only using 8 variables from each line of the array for each new row, the rest are either blank or manually placed.  However, none of the data is showing up in the new array to input into the other table.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it was my mistake - the values are 30. I'll offer you to use INSERT in form INSERT ... SET column=value, column=value .... And see what will be the error message. May be there are some restrictions and some of unused column can't be empty.